# Launch powershell script from UWP app with FullTrustProcessLauncher class

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Is there a way to launch powershell script from my UWP app ?

I have read that we have to use the FullTrustProcessLauncher class but I don't understand how to use/implement it.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher

Samples:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/JourneyAcrossTheBridge/DesktopBridgeDemo%20-%20Step4/MyUWPApp

https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLServer

In a nutshell, here is what you need to do:

1) add reference to the Desktop Extension SDK

2) declare the windows.FullTrustProcess extension in your manifest

3) (optional) declare an app service for communicating between your UWP and the fulltrust process

4) include a Win32 EXE in your package that will get launched from the FullTrustProcessLauncher API

5) that Win32 EXE can now invoke your powershell, etc.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but must it be running as console application? Changing backgroundprocess to Windows Application doesn't work

Comment: Please ask a new question with details of what you tried and what didn't work for you. You can set up the Win32 process either as Console application or Windows application, depending on the experience you want to create for your users.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987917/launch-powershell-script-from-uwp-app-with-fulltrustprocesslauncher-without-cons