# UWP Fail to execute PowerShell Script

Tags: c#, powershell, uwp

I was trying to test use of PS in UWP project using this [sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/), but is not working, to see the output I'm using Debug.Write instead of Console.WriteLine.
Aparently it fails to initialize the Runspace inside the PowerShell object with the error

Runspace = 'PowerShellInstance.Runspace' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Using the same sample on a Console project targetting .NET 4.5 everything works Fine.

Any ideas how to use this sample in UWP project?

For the Assembly System.Management.Automation I'm using Nuget Package System.Management.Automation 6.1.2.

Apparently the PowerShell object fails to crete the RunSpace

Comment: Please provide a code sample and error message in your question.

Comment: The code for UWP is exactly the same as the link that I provided, but instead of using main I'm using other method to initialize and call the PowerShellExecutor.ExecuteAsynchronously(). The process completes without errors but the final output is  > "Execution has stopped. The pipeline state: Failed". If you analize the object PowerShellInstance after being created (inside the using statement) you ll see that fails to initialize the "Runspace".

Comment: Creating the Runspace manually I found that I needed to add all the missing references, Total of 21 and those add a couple more references automatically as well... Do we have a single Nuget package that contains all these missing references?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell commands don't get supported directly within a Universal Windows app. You could call the [Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher) APIs to launch the full-trust Win32 application within the same package from a UWP. Then, once you launch the win32 application, the win32 application will invoke your powershell.

@Stefan Wick has replied a similar thread: [Launch powershell script from UWP app with FullTrustProcessLauncher class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157327/launch-powershell-script-from-uwp-app-with-fulltrustprocesslauncher-class). Please check it for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this won't work since you need to create a separated app and what I need is a class/dll that I can reference directly from UWP project to manipulate data in and out from those methods. At this point I don't understand why Microsoft does not, yet made UWP fully compatible with System.Management.Automation / PowerShell....